# How to set Themename in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

To set `themeSystem` in Fullcalendar you use:

```
themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
```

But how do i set `themeName` ?
Does it even exist?

Take a look at this page:
https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.10.0/demos/themes.html

Here you can choose both Theme system & Theme name!

I've tried: `themeName: 'Lumen'`

Comment: Look at the [Javascript theme handling file](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.10.0/demos/js/theme-chooser.js) of that demo...you'll see that the theme name is just used to control precisely which CSS file (compatible with the selected theme system) is loaded, it's not related to fullCalendar directly. fullCalendar lets you select which theme system you want to use, and then leaves it to you to load an appropriate CSS file which is compatible with the selected system.

Comment: ok, thank you! That's all i could find to.